# How to use JSTL and other Spring tag in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, spring, jstl, jsp-tags

I have two files, first one is `list.jsp` and other one is `loadmore.js`
I am calling `loadmore.js` in `list.jsp` file. I want to use tags like `<spring:message code="loadMore" />` and `<c:out value="${loadmore}" />` in my JavaScript file. But I don't know how to use or import these libraries in JavaScript file.

Can you help how to do this?

---

**Update:** added the following to my configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.5</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.5</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But now I get the following message in my FireBug console.

```
missing ) after argument list console.log("<spring:message code="label.empty" />");
```

Comment: Per your JavaScript error, you need to use two different kinds of quotes like `'<spring:message code="label.empty" />'`.

Comment: I put different kinds of quotes and output was like this: `<spring:message code="label.empty" />` it didn't give me the value in property file.

Comment: I'm sure it didn't, but at least it got rid of the JavaScript error.

Comment: yes, it got rid of JS error, but it didn't give me correct output. It must give 'No more value' instead of `<spring:message code="label.empty" />`

Comment: I'd really suggest you find a way to embed this stuff in your html page instead of in your js file in the first place.  Maybe in a hidden div, or as `data-` attributes on the appropriate elements.

Comment: Now these are in my html page and works well, I want to put them on a js page but I couldn't :(

Answer (score 2):

You can put all your external JavaScript inside a function that accepts variables defined in a  `<script>` tag inside the *.jsp*.

In your *.jsp* (I'm using jQuery):

```
<script src='<spring:url value="/resources/script.js"/>'></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    var messages = {
        some_message: '<spring:message code="some.message" text="some.message"/>'   
    };

    init(messages);
});
```

And then in your *.js* file:

```
function init(msg) {
    console.log(msg.some_message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use JSP tags in a JS file, you need to apply your JSP Engine to it (e.g. Jasper in case of a Tomcat server). To do that, you could add the following to you `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? You might have to add the Jasper servlet in the `web.xml` file.